# Simplest vector parametric expression?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the simplest vector parametric expression r(t) for the line that passes through the points P=(-2,3,1) at time t=3 and Q=(2,-2,-3) at time t=8.

I get r(t) = <-2+4t, 3-5t, 1-4t>, however this is wrong. Help?!

Comment: show your work.

Comment: What have you learned that mighy apply directly here?

Comment: Not much, I'm studying this on my own and trying to figure it out but I haven't found any help on this particular type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a line in space is in the form $r(t) = \textbf{p}+t\textbf{v}$ ,where $\textbf{p}$ is a vector on the line and $\textbf{v}$ is the vector parallel to the line, so you have 
$$r(3)=\textbf{p}+3\textbf{v}=(-2,3,1)$$ and
$$r(8)=\textbf{p}+8\textbf{v}=(2,-2,-3)$$

From here, you have two equations and two unknowns, you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!